# Email template - target specific email client (gmail)

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-email, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am building an email template and I am wondering if it is possible to target specific email clients (for example Gmail) to display content only when the email is viewed using those specific clients.

For example, is there a way to display this only to email viewed in gmail?

```
<div class="gmailOnly">This text will be displayed in Gmail only</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: In the general case, no; there is no guarantee even that the client will render HTML.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you. I could not find any documentation

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to target Gmail and Inbox for the moment. You need to take advantage of the fact that the HTML is modified before it would hit the rendering engine (as in most email clients) and in these email clients the message body will start with `<u></u>` tags. 
This:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head>
    <style>
        u + .body .gmail{
            display:block !important;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body class="body">
      <div class="gmail" style="display:none;">
        THIS IS GMAIL OR INBOX
      </div>
    </html>
```

will get converted to this:

```
    <u></u>    
    <div class="m_-4764228206553811341body">
      <div class="m_-4764228206553811341gmail" style="display:none">
        THIS IS GMAIL OR INBOX
      </div>
      <div class="yj6qo"></div>
      <div class="adL"></div>
    </div>
```

The `<u>` tags are specific to Inbox and Gmail clients. The `div`s from the original template therefore will only show in those these clients.

Comment: Even so, this is only for the Gmail App - iOS and Android - and not Gmail rendered via a browser, nor Gmail IMAP/POP (where people use custom domain names through Gmail).

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there isn't anyway of targeting gmail clients only, like you can do with `<!--[if gte mso 9]>` for Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

**Outlook App (iOS/Android)**

To hide an element from the Outlook app we can use the below snippet of CSS. The attribute [data-outlook-cycle] is added to the  element of all emails in these apps. We can then target elements with a class, such as .outlookhide in the below example:

```
<head>
<style>
body[data-outlook-cycle] .outlookhide {display:none!important;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="outlookhide">Content hidden from Outlook app on Android and iOS</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

**Outlook Webmail (outlook.com)**

To target Outlook webmail we take advantage of the way it adds x_ to all classes we use in our HTML. The CSS target attribute can be used to target any class containing x_[your class] by adding the operator ~ . In the example below we use the class “hideoutlookweb”.

```
<head>
<style>
[class~="x_hideoutlookweb"] {display:none!important;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="hideoutlookweb">Content hidden from Outlook.com</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Also there is few other ways to hide on outlook as :

```
<!--[if !mso]>
CONTENT
<!--<![endif]-->
```

You can also target specific versions of outlook as:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
CONTENT (versions greater or equal to mso 9)
<!--<![endif]-->
```

To hide from outlook desktop or windows mail (not web or mobile app) there is also this way:

```
<span style="mso-element:field-begin;"></span>
 Content to hide from Outlook 
<span style="mso-element:field-end;"></span>
```

**Gmail**

Hide content from Gmail – This CSS works due to Gmail converting the  tag to  so adding class=”body” to your  tag and then targeting the elements you want to hide from Gmail with a class, in the example below called “nogmail” and using display:none; to hide the content, make it not clickable, hidden from site, take up no space and not be seen by screen readers. Adding a media query around this CSS could choose to hide the content only on mobile screens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
u + .body .nogmail {display:none!important;}
</style>
</head>
<body class="body">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="nogmail">Content hidden from Gmail</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Yahoo and AOL**

Yahoo and AOL fairly recently started to use the same rendering engine and therefore can be targeted together using the below CSS snippet. A wrapping div is added with the class .& so we can target specific elements by chaining the classes together:

```
<head>
<style>
.& .yahooaol {display:none!important;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="yahooaol">Content hidden from Yahoo and AOL</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

To target just Yahoo you can add a div around the element with a unicode id name – aol strips that style, so it will only affect Yahoo.

```
<head>
<style>
  .& #★ .hideyahoo {display:none!important;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<div id="★">
<td class="hideyahoo">Content hidden from Yahoo only</td>
  </div>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

These tips were found in this great [blog](http://www.emaildesignreview.com/email-code/hiding-elements-in-email-4922/) on how to hide elements for some specific email providers as outlook, gmail, yahoo.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29166463)

Comment: Seemd too long and redundant to paste here, but got ur point, done.