# How can I adapt my email html depending on email account?

Tags: html-email, sendgrid

I create a template in SendGrid but the css works on Gmail but it doesn't work on Outlook.
I wanted to know if there is any solution to show a part of my code if the user have a gmail account, and do the same for outlook ?

I see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45740386/13000745

but when I inspect my HTML I don't see `<u>` tag.

Comment: you would need to write some code in the Sender to identify the receiver domain and if it matches a certain criteria then to send a certain type of HTML ; so `@hotmail.com` would load one HTML page and `@gmail.com` would load another, etc.

Comment: @Martin yes I want to do that so how can I go to sender to write the code ?

Comment: That is something you will need to do or you will need to contact SendGrid yourself and ask them. I would expect the easiest way around is that when you have a list of email addresses you split them into several smaller lists, a Gmail list, a Hotmail list and an Other list and then send them in three batches each using their own HTML

Comment: @Martin Unfortunately that method won't work. There are lots of people with custom domains that use Gmail, or whatnot. For example, office@stackoverflow.com could be using any number of email client.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not necessary to specifically target email clients, especially as the email clients keep getting updated.

The solution you linked to allows you to target Gmail App users, but not all Gmail users. For example, it doesn't work through Gmail on a browser (webmail), nor does it work for Gmail IMAP/POP users (those who use Gmail with a custom domain name). (But that solution does still work.)

To reiterate, it is not possible to deliver different content based on a person's email client with 100% accuracy (or even something possibly reasonable such as 95%). Unless of course you ask everyone.

As for getting the CSS to work, you must inline the CSS (use the style attribute in line with the HTML). You can use Campaign Monitor's tool to do that https://inliner.cm/